# Unable to get callback in closure in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callback, closures

I have viewcontroller from where i upload media to firebase & send url of media to my server as API call.Now for uploading images & call API i have created seprate class.There i have created a function which does the uploading work.

**OfflineSync Class Function**

```
 func UploadMediaToFireBase(sucess:@escaping ()->(),failure:@escaping (DIError)->()) {


            DIFirebaseImageManager.firebaseInstance.uploadImage(data: data, withName: filepath, mimeType: mimeType, progress: { (progress)
                in


            }) { (callback, firebaseUrl, error) in

                if let url = firebaseUrl {
                    self.uploadplace(place: self.place, done: {
                        sucess()
                        Utility.shared.hideLoader()

                    }, failed: { (result) in
                        failure(result)
                        Utility.shared.hideLoader()
                    })
                }

            }
        }
```

Now when i recive url i call this function in

```
 func uploadplace(place:place,done:@escaping ()->(),failed:@escaping (DIError)->()) {

            if let placeId = place.id {
                placeManager.shared.editplace(placeId: placeId, place: place, success: { (success) in
                    AlertBar.show(.success, message: AppMessages.place.placeEdited)

                    done()
                }, failure: { (failure) in
                    self.status = .cancelled
                    failed(failure)
                })
            }

    }
```

Once i uploading of media on firebase & url saved on my server  then i send callback to my controller as below code

```
   OfflineSync.shared.UploadMediaToFireBase(sucess: {
    DILog.print(items: "CallBack to MediaController")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }, failure: { (failure) in

    })
    }
```

But issue is i never get any callback to my controller.I get callback of `uplaodplace` to `uplaodmediatofirebase` function.But i never get callback to my controllrer.Please tell what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling closure methods on Main thread,

Ex,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    sucess()
}
```

Similar for,

- `failure(result)`
- `done()`
- `failed(failure)`

And for others.

**Refactoring code**,

Also it seems you have not handled else conditions for `if let` statements.

```
if let url = firebaseUrl {
                    self.uploadplace(place: self.place, done: {
                        sucess()
                        Utility.shared.hideLoader()

                    }, failed: { (result) in
                        failure(result)
                        Utility.shared.hideLoader()
                    })
                }else{
                        failure(failureResult)
                }
```

And also for this,

```
if let placeId = place.id {
                placeManager.shared.editplace(placeId: placeId, place: place, success: { (success) in
                    AlertBar.show(.success, message: AppMessages.place.placeEdited)

                    done()
                }, failure: { (failure) in
                    self.status = .cancelled
                    failed(failure)
                })
            }else{
                    failed(someFailure)
            }
```

Comment: I am not able to solve this issue.Still not able to get the callback.I have added method in main thread

Comment: What is the value of `failure` in `failure: { (failure) in`?

Comment: And show the code of `editplace`, it maybe having the issue.